# After clean build in xcode getting no such module on all imports

Tags: swift, xcode, build, cocoapods

My code was running fine, but after clean build (cmd+shift+k) all of sudden i started getting no such module found on all my imports. I tried delete derived data, clean build, Pod deintegrate and pod install but still getting this error. I'm using M1 and xcode 13.1. The same code run fine on intel machine or when opened using rosseta on M1.

Looking forward for the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning derived data?

Comment: Yes, both deleted derived data and clean build it.

Comment: Welcome onboard Ahmad! It looks like this is your first post. Note that the more your question is precise and structured, the greater your chances are to be helped. For example, you could provide cocoapods version, the precised error that pod or xcode gives you, your podfile, pod configurations, and so on. Look at how other questions are made and try to kinda replicate it. Hope you'll find a solution. .o/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens, but one way to solve your issue is to go into your
build settings and defining the Framework Search Paths to a folder which contains
the frameworks in question. If the frameworks are placed in your project directory,
simply set the framework search path to **$(SRCROOT)** and set it to recursive.

Comment: it didn't work, furthermore when i open it using rosseta code works fine.